# How do I pass parameters correctly to a 64-bit DLL from Windows Excel or MATLAB?

Tags: c

Here's an example of a test function in the DLL. The message box just displays what the function sees as the input parameter.

```
double __declspec(dllexport) LONGtest(long input)
{
char buf[50];
sprintf(buf,"input %ld",input;
MessageBox(0,buf,"LONG test",MB_ICONINFORMATION);
return (double)input;
}
```

The function works when called from a Windows 64-bit console test program but not when called from Excel or MATLAB. When called from MATLAB or directly from an Excel worksheet, the messagebox displays a large negative number instead of the input value. That number doesn't change if I change the input value from say "10" to "15". Oddly, if I create another function in the Excel Visual Basic editor with a different name "LONGtestVB" that in turn simply calls LONGtest, I get the correct answer when I call "LONGtestVB" from the Excel worksheet. The function also works when the DLL is compiled as a 32-bit DLL and called from 32-bit versions of Excel or MATLAB.

I can work around the problem in Excel using the method mentioned above but I can't find a similar way to do it in MATLAB.

I've tried using the cdecl calling convention instead of stdcall, but that doesn't solve the problem; according to what I've read about 64-bit windows, there's only one calling convention anyway so the "stdcall" and "cdecl" statements are ignored by the compiler.

Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Typo, you forget to close `sprintf` `)`

Comment: Why don't you change it to `unsigned long long` and `%llu` just to be on the safe side? (`long` tends to be of different sizes on different platforms).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I tried it with different data types - short, float, double -- and they all had the same problem. I've also used two different compilers, MinGW64 and Builder XE8, and the problem is still there. I'd like to figure out what's different in a call to a DLL from MATLAB or directly from an Excel worksheet than from an Excel VB function or a console program written in C -- if I knew that maybe I could somehow fix the problem.